When to call rospy.init_node() in a ROS client?
I am new to developing ROS services and clients. All of the tutorials I found online are quite simple. Most refer to the client as the client node yet I never see a call to rospy.init_node(). Is the client actually a ROS node? For a client, when should I call rospy.init_node() ? What purpose would it serve?

The client is a node. However, for clients you don't have to call the init_node() You can first call rospy.wait_for_service() (Source: https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29)
The purpose of the call is to initialize the ROS node for the process. It registers the client node with the master under the specified name (Source: https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy-module.html#init_node)
Here is an example that uses rospy.init_node() in the client node code. https://youtu.be/Dd3K1QYkvU0?feature=shared&t=138 . And I would recommend always using the rospy.init_node() as your first call so that you can give your node a clear and meaningful name.
